# "Einmal" als Zusatz zu einer Bitte in Norddeutschland

Tags: meaning-in-context, dialect, colloquial, northern-german

Ich komme aus dem Süden und in Norddeutschland ist mir aufgefallen, wie oft dort eine Bitte oder Aufforderung mit dem Wort "einmal" eingeleitet wird:

- Einmal die Fahrscheine bitte.
- Einmal bitte unterschreiben.
- Einmal zur Seite!
- Einmal dort drüben warten.

Wenn ich das unerwartet höre, bin ich im ersten Moment immer leicht irritiert, weil ich bei der Verwendung des Wortes "einmal" erwarte, dass es tatsächlich darum geht, eine Sache genau 1 Mal zu tun und nicht etwa öfter. Warum soll ich z. B. öfter als **ein**mal ins Wartezimmer gehen?

Mich würde interessieren, ob meine Vermutung richtig ist, dass das eine norddeutsche Erscheinung ist und ich nicht der einzige Süddeutsche bin, dem das leicht merkwürdig vorkommt.

Comment: Eigentlich muss es *Mal die Fahrscheine bitte.* heißen, aber das ist dem Kondukteur dann wohl doch wieder zu salopp.

Comment: Ich denke, dass es sich bei *mal* und *einmal* um [Füllwörter](https://conterest.de/fuellwoerter-liste-worte/) handelt, und nicht um eine Angabe der Anzahl von Vorgängen.

Comment: Nicht nur im Norden: *könnet ihr bitte ämol äweng ruhiger sei?* - *ganget ämol do nüber* (Schwäbisch/Alemannisch) - ich habe den Eindruck, hier ersetzt es sogar oft das *Bitte*.

Comment: @Takkat, stimmt, ich sage auch "Gib ma amåj d'Fernbedienung". Ich würde als Schaffner aber nie "Oamåj d'Fahrkàrtn bitte!" sagen.

Comment: Vermutlich ist _mal_ von _einmal_ abgeleitet und nicht umgekehrt. Die Normalform wäre eigentlich immer _einmal_, das wird abgekürzt zu _mal_ ('bitte mal / einmal tief einatmen'). Die Liste von @guidot ist interessant, aber der Begriff 'Fülllwort' taugt nicht als grammatische Kategorie. _Mal/einmal_ sind Zeitadverbien. So wie beschrieben steht _einmal_ meist in Aufforderungen am Satzanfang oder hinter _bitte, jetzt, als nächstes, dann..._, es markiert die **Reihenfolge**. Es kann stark oder halb betont sein. _Bitte mal die Fahrausweise_ wäre vllt. etwas salopp oder zu leger-fordernd.

Comment: Eine kommunikative Funktion des *Einmal* am Satzanfang ist, den Adressaten ein Signal zu geben "Achtung, jetzt kommt eine Nachricht". Wenn man gleich mit der eigentlichen Nachricht "Fahrkarten bitte" ins Haus fiele, könnte der Anfang der Botschaft möglicherweise der Aufmerksamkeit entgehen. Außerdem gibt es eine Grundregel in der linguistischen Pragmatik, die sagt: Je länger eine Ausdrucksform ist, als desto höflicher wird sie empfunden. Entsprechend wird "Einmal die Fahrkarten bitte" als höflicher empfunden als nur "Die Fahrkarten bitte".

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann: Das einmal als Antwort posten, bitte!

Comment: @Daniel: dito! :

Answer (score 3):

Einmal/Mal ist nur ein Füllwort, welches landesweit ständig zum Einsatz kommt. Regional kann es mal (!) mehr oder weniger eingesetzt werden. In Mitteldeutschland und nördlich völig normal.

Es gibt auch Gegenden, wo z.B. "manchmal" als Füllwort verwendet wird (z.B. "Kannst du mir manchmal sagen, ob du heute halb 3 Zeit hast?" - das gleiche in grün sozusagen. Es hat einfach keine tiefere Bedeutung.

Comment: Mal interessehalber: in welchen Gegenden wird _manchmal_ wie in Deinem Beispiel verwendet?

Comment: @Marzipanherz: im Raum Cottbus/Senftenberg

Comment: Es gibt einen Raum Cottbus/Senftenberg?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Falls dir die Wendung "im Raum" nicht geläufig ist (?): https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/im+raum+von.html Ansonsten verstehe ich die Frage nicht.

Answer (score 2):

> dass es tatsächlich darum geht, eine Sache genau 1 Mal zu tun und nicht etwa öfter.

Aber genau darum geht es in all deinen Beispielen für gewöhnlich, und genau das soll meines Erachtens auch zum Ausdruck kommen: Dadurch, dass man etwas nur *ein Mal* tun soll (nicht mehrfach, und tendenziell auch nicht für einen längeren Zeitraum), wird angedeutet, dass es sich nicht um eine umfangreiche Bitte handelt, man also keine große Forderung stellt und man folglich auch nicht beabsichtigt, dem Angesprochenen einen erheblichen Aufwand aufzubürden, um die Bitte zu erfüllen.

Dass das Word "einmal" die Bitte *einleitet*, mag in der Tat eher im Norden vorkommen. Wörter an beliebiger Stelle in der Aufforderung, die zum Ausdruck bringen, dass der Sprecher keine große Belastung für den Angesprochenen erzeugen möchte, kommen aber meinem Eindruck nach im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum vor:

- "mal" (direkte Verkürzung von "einmal")
- "kurz"
- "schnell"
- "geschwind"

Answer (score 2):

Kurze Antwort: Das ist einfach ein **Weckruf**.

Das Wörtchen "einmal" wird hier nicht ob seiner gewöhnlichen Bedeutung (semantisch!) verwendet, sondern es dient hier (pragmatisch!) zur Etablierung des Kommunikationskanals. Bei der Ansprache von Leuten, mit denen die Kommunikation noch nicht etabliert ist, ist es üblich (weil nützlich), irgend eine Lautäußerung voranzustellen, welche auch immer.

Andere gängige Rufsignale sind.

> Verzeihung!
>
> Schullijung!
>
> Hallo!
>
> Moin!
>
> Alle mal herhören!
>
> Obacht!
>
> Meine Damen und Herren!

In elektrischen Ansagesystemen wird das verbale Wecksignal üblicherweise ersetzt durch irgend ein Klingelzeichen, Tuut-Signal o.ä.

Der Zweck dabei ist, die Leute zum Zuhören zu bringen, so dass sie bei der Sache sind, wenn der eigentlich Inhalt der Botschaft kommt: "Die Fahrkarten bitte!"